# I have a problem with pprint in python

Tags: python, list, format, nested, pprint

I have looked into the pprint function, which i tried below:

```
from pprint import pprint
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
pprint(a)
```

But it didn't give me what i want, which is:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Is there a simple way to solve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either do what Ignacio said or change the width of pprint:

```
>>> pprint.pprint([[1,2],[3,4]], width=10)
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4]]
```

But you would have to calculate the space that your list takes...

Comment: I think this is the solution i ask for. Just curious what does the width=10 do?

Comment: the maximum amount of space for each line. You would have to change this number for your needs

Comment: how do you come up with number 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

That's... not what `pprint` does.

```
for i in a:
  print ' '.join(i)
```

Comment: Then either you've lied in your question, or you have one very messed up version of `pprint`.

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found. this is what i get when i try your solution